# Kubuntu 20.04 Shutdown/Reboot Hangs At "Waiting for process: crond"

Tags: systemd, shutdown, kubuntu

I'm running Kubuntu 20.04.  3 out of 4 times when I shutdown or reboot, it hangs at:

```
 Reached target Reboot.
 systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: crond
```

I've spent a fair bit of time googling, but have unable to figure out why it's doing this.  It makes frequent reboots agonizingly slow.  I did find one thread describing the same issue on the [Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2442125), but they failed to post their solution (just that they solved it).

Any help or info would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the same happen when you use `dcron`  instead of `crond`? Have you always been having this problem or is it something that arouse after taking some action?

Comment: This is a relatively fresh Kubuntu install, and I'm relatively new to Linux. I was basically working on getting everything installed, and at some point, this radomly started happening.  It's unclear exactly when, particularly because it only occurs intermittently.  Not sure what I would need to change to 'use dcron instead of crond'?

Comment: Check ubuntu form https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2442125&p=14021734#post14021734

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same problem. When shutdown it displays

> systemd-shutdown [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjPFP.png): waiting for process: crond

and wait for some time (more than a minute) and it shutsdown.

I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**
I googled it and found the solution. I installed Bleachbit from official site: https://www.bleachbit.org/download/linux and link to file: https://www.bleachbit.org/download/file/t?file=bleachbit_4.2.0-0_all_ubuntu2004.deb

**Install:** Just right click it and select Open with other app and select Software install
Or by command line: sudo install < file >

After success install you can see it in Application list, select bleachbit admin and run it.
List is in attachment image(screenshot).
[image]

After this. For First time shutdown it took some time (More than a min) and it did't display any error, and shutdown.

After that everything is normal, now it shutdown fast. I tested many times, it's working good.

Comment: Thanks - I can confirm that Bleachbit fixed the issue.  I actually found this solution elsewhere & forgot to note it here, so thanks for posting!

Answer (score 5):

Cron can hang if one of its jobs is hanging (for example if you have a misconfigured log rotation, etc.).

To find the culprit run pstree before you reboot to see if any processes are active/hanging:

```
pstree -ap $(pidof cron)
```

You can also look what cron jobs are defined in

```
/etc/crontab  
/etc/cron.d/  
/etc/cron.daily/  
/etc/cron.hourly/  
/etc/cron.monthly/  
/etc/cron.weekly/
```

as well as `crontab -l` (for each user).

If this does not help you solve your problem you can use this as a workaround:

- edit `/etc/systemd/system.conf`
- set DefaultTimeoutStopSec in the Manager section

  ```
  [Manager]
  DefaultTimeoutStopSec=5s
  ```
- run `systemctl daemon-reload`

This will tell systemd to only wait for 5 seconds for the crond process to exit.

Comment: Even after setting timeout to 5 seconds it's still taking around 3 minutes to shutdown and the same message pops up (waiting for process crond)

Comment: Since this is not your question you cannot update it with the output of `journalctl -b -1 -r` ...? check if there are any messages related to crond. It should say "Shutting down." before "Reached target Reboot." (the log is reversed with -r)

Answer (score 4):

Same problem on my Xubuntu 20.04 since 2 weeks.

In order to find out the origin of this message displayed at shutdown

```
Reached target Reboot.
systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: crond
```

I used this command to get the cron jobs files list (ordered by date) :

```
find /etc/cron* -type f | xargs  ls -ltr
```

I discovered that the file **/etc/cron.d/collect** ( freshly updated ) was scheduling a weird binary named **/var/tmp/crond**

My solution to disable this job was to move **/etc/cron.d/collect** elsewhere (in my home directory, so as to try before deleting it forever).

After 2 reboots I checked that I recovered a fast shutdown !

(can also follow this link : https://askubuntu.com/a/1329933 )

Comment: I had the same issue. This worked. Thanks

Comment: In case you two happen to come back across this page, you may have been infected by a weaponised .deb file of Free Download Manager.
https://securelist.com/backdoored-free-download-manager-linux-malware/110465/

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm the answer of gilles gaido.
In my case these files

- **/etc/cron.d/collect**
- **/var/tmp/crond**
- **/var/tmp/bs**

were probably created by "Free Download Manager" version 6.X

Removing this software did not remove these files, so I did what gilles gaido describes but additionally removing **/var/tmp/bs**

**Edit**: As a comment mentions, the setup file for linux at the "Free Download Manager" website was malicious. Additionally delete the file:

- **/var/tmp/atd**

Comment: Oh interesting! I also have Free download Manager, so I guess that's pretty definitive evidence for what caused it.

Comment: Free download manager is the culprit for me too. For me I only had the /etc/cron.d/collect file to delete - the other files didn't exist.

Comment: Seems like you downloaded free download manager from a suspicious source & had malware installed on your computer: https://securelist.com/backdoored-free-download-manager-linux-malware/110465/

Answer (score 3):

If the problem is faced after installing "Free Download Manager", then you just got infected with Malware.

https://securelist.com/backdoored-free-download-manager-linux-malware/110465/

That mentioned crond process is the one used for persistence and C2 communication.